# String Aggregation of potentially empty fields without FILTER in postgres.

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

In Postgres I am trying to included a comma separated list of linked ip addresses to a particular server in the result rows of server data.

Initialially I used the FILTER functionality which seemed ideal for my purposes

```
STRING_AGG(ipadd, ',') FILTER ( WHERE ipadd is NULL OR ipadd != '') AS ipaddresses
```

Producing results lines such as

```
  server1;data;etc; 1.2.3.4;
  server2;data;etc; 11.22.33.44, 22.33.44.55;
  server3;data;etc;
  server3;data;etc; 23.45.67.89
```

However, it has come to light that the server this will be running on uses a lower version postgresql which does not support the FILTER functionality.

Due to this I needed to simplify the call to

```
STRING_AGG(ipadd, ',') AS ipaddresses
```

Which due to the existence of potentially empty or null entries in the multiple rows returned from the second table, returns something like the following:

```
  server1;data;etc; ,1.2.3.4,,,;
  server2;data;etc; 11.22.33.44,,, 22.33.44.55,,,;
  server3;data;etc; ,,,,,,,,,
  server3;data;etc; ,,23.45.67.89,,
```

Each empty or null entry produces another empty field which is included with the correct data.

Is there a pre-FILTER way of achieving the same results as the FILTER query above, or even just removing all instances of commas that aren't separating two returned pieces of data.

At present I'm just parsing these out on the server side after the call, but I would prefer to do it on the SQL side of things if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`string_agg()` will ignore `null` values anyway so the filter on `is null` isn't really necessary.

The filter condition `ipadd <> ''` can be replaced by simply "converting" an empty string to a `null` value (which in turn will then be ignored by the aggregate function)

```
string_agg(nullif(ipadd,''), ',')
```

Comment: Very quick and effective. Ideal for my purposes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would replace the `filter` with `case`:

```
STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN ipadd is NULL or ipadd <> '' THEN ipadd END, ','
          )  AS ipaddresses
```